# Adding a simple GET or POST in ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I know what GET and POST methods are in ajax, but i was wondering how to implement them into a simple code so i can understand it better, and here's a simple code i found:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>XMLHttpRequest in Mozilla</title>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function Start()
{
try
{
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
document.getElementById("Content").innerHTML="<h1>Using XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>";
}
catch (e)
{
document.getElementById("Content").innerHTML="<h1>XMLHttp cannot be created!</h1>";
}  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:Start()">Start</a>
<div id="Content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you're achieving there is to determine whether your browser supports XMLHttpRequest or not (no in explorer, yes on anything else). You are not actually calling the server.

This is a nice link to start learning ajax and javascript in general:

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/AJAX_for_n00bs

Be sure you check all the site, not only that post.

```
function ajaxRequest() {
   var AJAX = null;                                 // Initialize the AJAX variable.
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {                     // Does this browser have an XMLHttpRequest object?
      AJAX=new XMLHttpRequest();                    // Yes -- initialize it.
   } else {                                         // No, try to initialize it IE style
      AJAX=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  //  Wheee, ActiveX, how do we format c: again?
   }                                                // End setup Ajax.
   if (AJAX==null) {                                // If we couldn't initialize Ajax...
      alert("Your browser doesn't support AJAX.");  // Sorry msg.                                               
      return false                                  // Return false, couldn't set up ajax
   }
   var url='http://somedomain.com/getdata.php?doc=sometext.txt'; // This is the URL we will call.
   AJAX.open("GET", url, true);                                  // Open the url this object was set-up with.
   AJAX.send(null);                                              // Send the request.

   AJAX.onreadystatechange = function() {                      // When the browser has the request info..
       if (AJAX.readyState==4 || AJAX.readyState=="complete") { //  see if the complete flag is set.
          callback(AJAX.responseText, AJAX.status);             // Pass the response to our processing function
       }                          

                          // End Ajax readystate check.
   }                                                           // End Event Handler.
}
```

Comment: i know javascript pretty well, jus new to ajax xD

Comment: Well that link should be all you need then. Adding a sample from that doc in the answer...

Answer (score 2):

A good place to get started : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/

Your snippet of code will only work in non IE browsers. Don't leave MS out of the party! Use this code

```
var httpRequest;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
    httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

Now you can use this object to carry out a request or two.

There's a very comprehensive tutorial here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started

That tutorial will explain it much better than I ever can.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest something that will make your life a whole lot easier. Use jQuery! It makes ajax calls (and anything javascript) much easier. You can do complex operations with very little code.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
This is for your refrence.

Comment: hehe, ive looked at jquery, im SO confused about it :P

Comment: I find plain javascript very useful for simple calls. I'm not saying that jQuery is not a great library for anything else tho!

Comment: I just think that if your gonna learn a new skill, you might as well get some extra milage from it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are really into Javascript and want to learn AJAX in simple way, I would suggest you the http://w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp which is pretty basic and easy to understand. You can even try out there what you have learnt so far.

Also, Jquery is pretty simple as far as Ajax is considered. It basically frees you from all the mess of checking for the browser compatibilities and other stuff. I suggest you take a look at what Elad has mentioned in the above. "Write Less Do more" is the tag for Jquery. Just give it a try.